# C# WinForm Image Folder instead of Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement for my `WinForm` Application for showing SVG icons instead of traditional png icons.

There is a SVG Rendering Library 1.6.1 that does the work but only works for file system files, so If I try to Embedded a SVG as a resources the library can't process that stream.

Basically, my question is how can I add a image folder, so when I publish my application (clickonce) the folder is created with the images inside.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a fast reading of the SVG library, it appears that [SvgDocument](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgDocument.cs) does support a `stream` interface; in particular `public static T Open<T>(Stream stream) where T : SvgDocument, new()`.

Comment: Yes, it seems it does support, but it doesn't. You can try it.

Comment: Then just raise an issue with them.